# calculating Lebesgue-Integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

How does the equation come up:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \theta e^{\theta x} Q(x,\infty) \lambda (dx)= \int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{\theta x}-1) Q(dx)$

with $Q$ is a measure and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I calculated:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \theta e^{\theta x} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbf{1}_{(x,\infty)} (y) Q(dy) \lambda(dx)$

$= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \theta e^{\theta x}  \mathbf{1}_{(x,\infty)} (y) \lambda(dy) Q(dx)$

$= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{x}^{\infty}  \theta e^{\theta x} \lambda(dy) Q(dx)  $

but don’t know how to come to $\int_{0}^{\infty} (e^{\theta x}-1) Q(dx)$.

KR, toni

Answer (score 1):

It comes from a known result (*). Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $u:X\to [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function. Let $\phi:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be increasing and s.t. $\phi(0)=0$ and continuously differentiable. Then
$$\int_X \phi(u(x))\mu(dx)=\int_{(0,\infty)}\phi'(t)\mu(\{x:u(x)\geq t\})dt$$
where the rhs is an improper Riemann integral. In our case, $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)=(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^+),Q)$, $u(x)=x$, $\phi(y)=e^{\theta y}-1$. Thus
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+}(e^{\theta x}-1)Q(dx)=\int_{(0,\infty)}\theta e^{\theta t}\underbrace{Q(\{x:x\geq t\})}_{=Q([t,\infty))}dt$$

---

(*) The gist of the proof is
$$\begin{aligned}\int_X \phi(u(x))\mu(dx)&=\int_{(0,\infty)}\mu(\phi\circ u\geq t)dt=\\
&=\int_{(0,\infty)}\mu(\phi\circ u\geq \phi(y))\phi'(y)dy=\\
&=\int_{(0,\infty)}\mu(u\geq y)\phi'(y)dy
\end{aligned}$$
but some technicalities are to be considered.